# What permissions are needed to administer IIS without being 'administrator'?

Tags: iis, administration

Is there a way to set up a user group that has permissions to administrate IIS services (use the IIS plugin in MMC) without being a 'Administrator' on the box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, if it's IIS6, then you need to be local admin. If it's IIS7 then things are significantly more granular. If you're planning to move to IIS7 (or currently use it) then there's a good [blog post here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/thoughts-on-delegating-iis-configuration-and-administration) that takes you through it.